# What is the test used in R in sm.regression to compare reference model with kernel regression?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I am doing bivariate kernel regression using the sm.regression function:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sm/sm.pdf

There is an option to compare the nonparametric estimate with linear model. When requested, it returns p-value that the nonparametric estimate is not different from the linear (null hypothesis).

Does anyone know what test is used to calculate the p-value? I can't find it anywhere.

The answer might be in:
Bowman, A.W. (2006). Comparing nonparametric surfaces. Statistical Modelling, 6, 279-299.

Thank you!